# Want to replace old-3way with occupancy sensor but stumped because switch is so old

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have this old 3-way switch and want to replace it with an occupancy sensor but all three screws seem to be hot and they are all dark color, not sure how to identify the true 'hot' wire.

Pics:
[image]

[image]

Thx in advance

<strike>p.s. A klein tool indicated all 3 as hot and the multimeter red probe on each (with the black probe on the wallbox metal) indicated 120v on all 3.</strike>

2nd switch.

<strike>ok, so I opened the other switch (which coincidentally does not operate if the 1st 3-way is 'off').
When the 1st 3-way is 'on' all three wires on the 2nd switch are hot. When the 1st switch is 'off' then only the red in the 2nd switch is hot. Also, I could not get a 'ground' between the red and the wallbox.</strike>

https://i.imgur.com/Jfz4BGO.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/X0yNSRU.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/ZMx8lvB.jpg

p.s. I have a follow-up question. The sensor I have does not require neutral but it does require a ground. There's no ground wire present but the wallbox itself seems to be grounded. What's the best practice to attach the ground sensor wire to the wallbox? Thx

Comment: I would turn off the breaker and gently try to clean the screws.  One screw should be a different colour.  A damp cloth should be enough.

Comment: Will do. As you can see, this switch is old and doesn't seem to conform to what all modern switches look like.

Comment: All screws are same color, clean up did not do anything...Thx

Comment: Why have you struck-through all that text? What are you trying to tell us by that? You haven't added anything to replace it.

Answer (score 2):

The common is almost always going to be the one terminal at one end away from the other two at the other end (due to physical construction of switches, internally.) I would, however, agree that cleaning as @crip659 suggests should confirm that.

Whether it's "true hot" or "switched hot to light" depends on which end of the 3-way circuit you are at. In any case you don't appear to have a neutral, so your choice of smart switch is limited.

Comment: Thx. The one in the pics is the one closest to the breaker box so I would expect it to have a true hot. I will check the 3-way that's furthest to see what kind of hotness it has.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I call a dead end 3way. There is no neutral available in this box. In fact, the white wire is the common connection and is always hot. (It will be connected to black at other end) the black and red are the travelers. Flipping this switch changes which of the black/red wires is also hot.

Both the power input and the switch leg to light are in other box, and would suggest placing smart switch at that end.

The best I can see in picture is that the black red white set of wires are the only ones in the box, indicating it is a dead end. That style of switch has the travelers as the two black screws at one end, and the common is a gold screw by itself at the other end.  Unless you have a switch failure, or a bad mis wiring at other end, there should only be 2 wires with a 120v to ground potential. That would the white one and which ever other one that switch is connected to. Have all 3 with line voltage is just another good reason to use the box at other end.

Just saw your edit for 2nd switch. Definitely miswired. I'm almost certain that if you swap the 2 black wires positions on that switch, you will have a functional, proper 3 way working. Both switches will turn on and off, and there will only be 2 hot wires of the 3 we been talking about. The white and either black or red depending on position 1st switch is in. If you dig into the 2nd box you will find the white wire connected to the incoming constant 120v black (maybe red) wire.

If you really want the smart switch at other box, and all you need is constant 120v + neutral or ground, you can the black going to 1st switch to the hot wire in 2gang box and connect the white to the other whites in that box. Then you have constant power in 1st box.

In your picture of 2nd switch:

The black wire on the gold screw across from red wire is the switch leg, (wire connected to light.)

The black wire connected to black screw is the one going to other switch.

Comment: How do you know the white is the common? That's what I am trying to determine, which one of these wires is the true hot.  Unfortunately with my tools (klein and multimeter) they all show as 'hot' 120v. p.s. I don't need a neutral, the sensored switch I bought does not require a neutral.

Comment: So, I removed all the wires from switch 1 & 2. Only white on switch 1 was 'hot'. Red on switch 2 was hot only when switch 1 was on. Next step was to replace switch 1 with a standard 2-way switch while switch 2 stays completely disconnected. So, a 2-way switch with white/red or white/black did not turn on the lights. My goal is to only keep switch location 1 with a sensot in it. So, I think something needs to be connected on switch location 2.

Comment: To just use your sensor in switch box 1 and eliminate switch 2 completely: in box 1, connect white wire to constant power on sensor. Then connect the black wire to the switched leg of your sensor. The red will be unused.  In box 2: connect both black wires off of switch 2 together with a wire nut. The red will be unused.  Assuming your sensor only needs the constant hot and the switched hot connected to it, and eliminating switch 2 completely, that will be all you need to do.

Comment: Thx, I ended up doing  something similar but used the red wire instead of the black and instead of tying the 2 wires together in location 2 I used a simple 2-way switch to connect them. Everything works perfectly when that 2-way switch is on...Thx